# How can I modify the content of default columns?

Tags: columns

I have a code to add content to my custom columns, that looks like this

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_custom_columns', 10, 2 );    
function my_custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'column1':
        echo 'output1';
        break;
        case 'column2':
        echo 'output2';
        break;
        case 'column3':
        echo 'output3';
        break;
    }
}
```

There is a way to do the same thing with default columns like the Title one?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this has been answered pretty well here.. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152971/replacing-the-title-in-admin-list-table