# Add acf field in title (admin table)

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, title, wp-list-table

I want to add an ACF field in my post title, only on admin table (not in the title field stored in database), and only for a specific Custom Post Type. Some of my posts have the same name, so it will be more useful to have this information. In final, my title will look like that :

```
$new_title = get_the_title($post->ID).' - '.get_field('place', $post->ID);
```

I have found other solutions on other topics, but all the post types are affected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to filter the title:

```
add_action(
    'admin_head-edit.php',
    'wpse264139_edit_post_change_title_in_list'
);
function wpse264139_edit_post_change_title_in_list() {
    add_filter(
        'the_title',
        'wpse264139_construct_new_title',
        100,
        2
    );
}`

`function wpse264139_construct_new_title( $title, $id ) {
    if(get_post_type($id) == 'post_type') {
       $field = get_field('place', $id);
       return $field . " " . $title;
    }
    else {
       return $title;
    }
}
```

NOTE: most of the code came from: [Replacing the title in admin list table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152971/replacing-the-title-in-admin-list-table)

Comment: Yes but how to hook for replacing the title in admin table List (for this post type only)?

Comment: Edited answer with get_post_type()