# Accepting certain HTML tags in WP List Table column data

Tags: wp-list-table, wp-kses

In my Custom Post Type (CPT), I altered the display of the post title using the method mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/152978/22728). But for my custom use case, I need to pass some HTML like `<sup></sup>`. But by default WP List Table class is designed to suppress any HTML tags using [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/).

But I can see there might be a provision accepting user-defined functions using PHP's [`call_user_func()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), but doesn't have any idea on how to do that.

I want to accept certain HTML tags using `wp_kses()` to the titles of my CPT in a certain use case like below:

> My Title<sup>2</sup>

Can it be possible?